# foreach loop - different class per item

Tags: php, foreach

I need to give a different class name to every 6 divs within a foreach loop. I thought my below idea would work, but every item seems to get the same div.

```
<?php $num = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($divs as $div): ?>

    <?php if($num % 1 == 0): ?>
    <div class="threecol grey one">
    <?php elseif($num % 2 == 1): ?>
    <div class="threecol green two ">
    <?php elseif($num % 3 == 2): ?>
    <div class="sixcol blue last three">
    <?php elseif($num % 4 == 3): ?>
    <div class="threecol grey">
    <?php elseif($num % 5 == 4): ?>
    <div class="sixcol blue">
    <?php elseif($num % 6 == 5): ?>
    <div class="threecol green last">
    <?php endif; ?>

        Rest of html

    </div>

<?php $num++ ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

To simplify i basically need

1st/7th/13th/19th...etc div to be `<div class="threecol grey">`

2nd/8th/14th/20th...etc to be `<div class="threecol green">`

3rd/9th/15th/21st...etc to be `<div class="sixcol blue last">`

4th/10th/16th/22nd  `<div class="threecol grey">`

5th/11th/17th/23rd  `<div class="sixcol blue">`

6th/12th/18th/24th  `<div class="sixcol blue">`

Comment: To avoid all these conditions, I would use an array with classes and use `class="<?php echo $classes[$num]; ?>"` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very ugly... why not

```
$classes = array('grey one', 'green two', 'blue last three', 'grey', 'blue', 'green last');
foreach($divs as $div) {
   $class = $classes[$i++ % 6];
   echo '<div class="threecol ' . $class . '">';
}
```

The main problem is that you're continually changing the divisor in your modulo operation, so you're always getting the 0 remainder.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the only answer that works. Probably my explanation wasn't clear enough. thx again

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the modulo operator which results in the remainder of the dividend.  Thus, `% 1` will *always* be zero because there is never a remainder with that operation.  You want to do this:

```
$num % 6 == 1
...
$num % 6 == 2
```

etc.  You can also just do `$num % 6` ahead of time and store it in a variable.

Comment: I think he wants a class for the num 0 to 5, another for 6 to 11, another for 12 to 17...

Comment: @MajidLAISSI in that case just increment `$num` every 6 entries instead of every entry.

Comment: actually i'm not sure what HE wants

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(floor($num / 6) == 0): ?>
<div class="threecol grey one">
<?php elseif(floor($num / 6) == 1): ?>
<div class="threecol green two ">
<?php elseif(floor($num / 6) == 2): ?>
<div class="sixcol blue last three">
<?php elseif(floor($num / 6) == 3): ?>
<div class="threecol grey">
<?php elseif(floor($num / 6) == 4): ?>
<div class="sixcol blue">
<?php elseif(floor($num / 6) == 5): ?>
<div class="threecol green last">
<?php endif; ?>
```

This would give:

- `threecol grey one` for columns from 0 to 5
- `threecol grey two` for columns from 6 to 11
- etc..

Comment: Thanks, maybe i didn't explain myself right, but i basically need to isolate 6 divs (every 6 divs). So to simplify, i need the 1st/7th/13th/19th...etc div to be `<div class="threecol grey">` then 2nd/8th/14th/20th...etc to be `<div class="threecol green">` then 3rd/9th/15th/21st...etc to be `<div class="sixcol blue last">`. I'll up date question.

Comment: well in this case checkout the other answers they have the solution you need

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($divs as $i => $div): ?>
    <?php if($i % 6 == 0): ?>
    <div class="threecol grey one">
    <?php elseif($i % 6 == 1): ?>
    <div class="threecol green two ">
    <?php elseif($i % 6 == 2): ?>
    <div class="sixcol blue last three">
    <?php elseif($i % 6 == 3): ?>
    <div class="threecol grey">
    <?php elseif($i % 6 == 4): ?>
    <div class="sixcol blue">
    <?php elseif($i % 6 == 5): ?>
    <div class="threecol green last">
    <?php endif; ?>
        Rest of html
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Consider use of a switch case statement.

Comment: I think he wants a class for the num 0 to 5, another for 6 to 11, another for 12 to 17...